# Loading channel error 800101 when loading group channels Sendbird

Tags: ios, swift, sendbird

I get the following error when I try to load the group channels in `Sendbird SDK` from the method:

```
self.groupChannelListQuery?.loadNextPage(completionHandler: { (channels, error) in }
```

> Error Domain=Connection required. Code=800101 "(null)"

Comment: check your connection may be your not connected to the server.https://docs.sendbird.com/ios/error_codes

Comment: Do I need to connect the user everytime I want to fetch the conversation? Currently I am connecting at the time of login only.

Comment: You don't need to connect every time but you need to check whether it is connected or not you can make common function for it.

Answer (score 0):

> From sendbird docs

**Note:** You must connect to SendBird server before calling any methods through the SDK (apart from initializing a SendBird instance). If you attempt to call a method without connecting, a SBDErrorConnectionRequired (800101) error would be returned.